# Android Studio Gradle compile not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit2

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 and I'm trying to get Retrofit working in Android Studio.  I've added this to the build.gradle associated with the project:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

Everything will build, but when I try to actually use Retrofit the library is not  recognized. I've tried executing "Sync Project With Gradle File" as well as running gradlew clean from the terminal. Neither of these has any effect.

Comment: Well, clean won't rebuild the project. Try `gradlew app:dependencies` to make sure it's there

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be very simple. I was adding lines to the pom.xml for the module rather than the app. Added them in the app's pom.xml and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried ,it works fine, you can try to modify your compileVersion ,buildtoolsVersion of a high version in your gradle,maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
```